# generate sequence in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'd like to create sequences using the definitions below:

```
(define f1 (lambda (x) #t))
(define f2 (lambda (x) #f))             
(define f3 (lambda (x) (if (null? x) #t (car x))))
(define f4 (lambda (x) (if (null? x) #t (not (car x)))))
```

My code is as follows:

```
(define (generate func n)
       (let ((mylist '()))
       (if (= n 0) mylist
        (cons (func mylist) (generate func (- n 1)))                
   )))
```

It does the trick for f1 f2 and f3 but when i try f4 like (generate f4 10) it produces 
(#t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t #t) instead of (#t #f #t #f #t #f #t #f #t #f).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it happens because each time `func` is called with `'()` which is the value of `mylist` in `let` scope. We should pass new list value to the next call of `generate` to do something useful with it. Something like this

```
(define (generate f n)
  (define (generate-int n lst)
    (if (= n 0) 
        lst
        (generate-int (- n 1) (cons (f lst) lst))))

  (generate-int n (list)))
```

Now `(generate f4 4)` produces `'(#f #t #f #t)` with first generated value coming last in the list. One may `reverse` the result to get a "natural" order or use `append` instead of `cons` which would be less effective.